# Define an operation on the Cartesian product $G = G_1 × G_2$ by $(x_1, y_1) * (x_2, y_2) = (x_1x_2, y_1y_2).$ Then choose the correct option

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $G_1 = \{1, −1, i, −i\}$ and $G_2 = \{1, \omega, \omega^2\}$, where $i = \sqrt{−1}$ and $\omega$ is a
complex cube root of $1$. Define an operation on the Cartesian product
$G = G_1 \times G_2$ by

$$(x_1, y_1) * (x_2, y_2) = (x_1x_2, y_1y_2).$$

Then choose the correct option:

(A) $(G,* )$ is not a group,

(B) $ (G, *) $ is a group but not cyclic,

(C) $(G, *)$ is a group but not commutative,

(D) $(G, *)$ is a commutative cyclic group.

My attempt : I thinks  option  (A) is correct because  inverse properties  will not hold

Any hints/solution will be appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: @Arthur ya inverse  will not exist

Comment: Given $(x,y)\in G$, is $(x^{-1},y^{-1})$ in $G$? What is $(x,y)*(x^{-1},y^{-1})$? Are you still claiming that we don't have inverses?

Comment: ya  $\frac{1}{0 }$ is not exist   @Arthur

Comment: You can't invert $0$. Sure. Is that an issue? Is $0$ in $G$?

Comment: okss  @Arthur..$0$ is not  in G  ..

Comment: that mean option d)  is correct? @Arthur

Comment: That's up to you. Is it a group? If so, is it commutative? If so, is it cyclic? These ought to be straightforward things to check.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** We have $i^4=1$ and $\omega^3=1$.

**Hint 2:** Every element of $G$ is a product of $(1, \omega)$ and $(i, 1)$ with respect to $\ast$. Do these particular elements commute? Can you write one as a power of the other?

*Hover over or click the box below for the solution.*

> The answer is (B) as $(G, \ast)$ is the [direct product](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct_product_of_groups) of $G_1$ and $G_2$ (as groups under multiplication).